# scala could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable]] ).asJson)

Tags: scala, circe

I am trying to encode a Map to Json using `io.cierce`

My Json data is like

```
{
   "key" : "123-456" ,
   "message" : "test msg",
   "payload" : { "hello" : "world" }
  }
```

And Json conversion

```
Map(
      "key" -> root.key.string.getOption(data).getOrElse(""),,
      "message" -> root.message.string.getOption(data).getOrElse(""),
      "payload" -> root.payload.json.getOption(data).getOrElse(Json.Null)
    ) asJson
```

But this is resulting `could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable]] ) asJson)`

I was under the impression `import io.circe.generic.auto._` should take care of most of the `encoding`

Comment: **circe** uses some typeclasses for encoding and decoding, and those typeclasses are derived at compile time. This, if the compiler can't know the structure of the data then it can't derive the information **circe** needs. You should use properly typed data like a case class.

Comment: Got it , but what about if my payload doesn't have a standard structure. Its not possible to have a case class for that.

Comment: How do you process something that you don't know how it looks like? Anyways, you can use the `JSON` that provides **circe** or use other library more intended to dynamic processing like **uJson**.

Comment: Actually at this point I am not processing anything for the `payload` , basically storing it for ref in DB . The problem is the `ORM` of that model field is `Option[Json]` , hence I need to encode it to Json as raw .

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

scala> Map("key" -> "hello".asJson, "boolean" -> true.asJson, "number" -> 123.asJson).asJson.spaces4 
res1: String =
{
    "key" : "hello",
    "boolean" : true,
    "number" : 123
}
```

You need to avoid Map[String, Any] and use the appropriate implicits to get the automatic conversion you need.

Comment: I didn't get that part , why we need `value`. `asJson` and then again `.asJson.spaces4 `

Comment: Also it will convert Json to String

Comment: The `.spaces4` converts to a string, you can remove that if needs be.

The reason you need .asJson inside and outside the Map is because you need the type to be `Map[String, Json]`. If you define an implicit to convert an Int to a json like this:
`implicit def numberToJson(i :Int) :Json = i.asJson` and some others, you can remove the .asJson's entirely.